# Unable to insert more rows with one query MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, rows

I can't insert multiple rows with just one query, and I can't understand why. The query should be fine.. here is my query example:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name, other, etc)
VALUES (value, value, value), (value, value, value), (value, value, value);
```

Comment: How about the actual query, or a closer representation of it?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: ...and a description of the problem you encounter; such as: does it error, is it accepted but only the first is put into the table, etc....

Comment: the query is a bit long , so I will write just a part , I have to insert every time 7 rows , one for every day of the week :

Comment: INSERT INTO overtimes (date, shift,...)
            VALUES (".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date_monday']).", ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['shiftid']).",...),

Comment: It doesn't say what error is.. when I try to save the form , a white page with the text " Error in query INSERT... : " and no error number..

Comment: Try inserting just 1 row and see if it works. The problem may be with mysqli_real_escape_string, we'll see.

Comment: I already tryed with just one row , and even without  mysqli_real_escape_string , just $_POST['shiftid'].. , and it doesn't work.. that's why I find it strange.. should be a very easy query..

Comment: Just to clarify, when you tried with just one row it worked, right?

Comment: No , it didn't worked even with one row , anyway another thing.. I have 42 fields to insert for each row.. that could be a problem ?

Comment: Idk if this would work but try removing the period in front of mysqli_real_escape_string so it would be like VALUES ("mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date_monday']).", "mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['shiftid']).",...)

Comment: Having 42 fields to insert shouldn't be a problem, just make sure that the number of fields in the INSERT INTO is the same amount as the number of fields within the VALUES. And the datatypes are correct.

Comment: If you're not inserting an ID also check to make sure that your table is auto-incrementing that identity, as this would cause an error.

Comment: I don't insert the id from the query , and yes it is auto-incremetnging.. you think this is the problem ?

Comment: Try to run your original version and when the error appear click with right button and see your page source the error MAY not be appearing because it could have  a `<` which turns the text into an html tag

Comment: tryed , no error anyway..

Comment: Try outputting your query string, instead of running it, to see exactly what it is that the code is trying to execute. (Also: You should be able to edit the question above, rather than adding bits and pieces in these comments.)